# How to reactivate wallet quick setting tile?

Tags: quick-settings, android-one, android-13, google-wallet

I have been using my phone to make contactless payments for about 2 years now. I could always access my virtual cards through the quick settings menu. To be honest I don't remember exactly how I set it up initially, but I didn't have the Google Wallet App installed before this issue occured.

When I wanted to pay today, I realized that the Wallet tile is greyed out. A quick online search did not provide any information other than it may be regionally locked.

After that I installed the Google Wallet app and upon opening it both my virtual cards show up just fine. I just can't get the Quick setting tile to work. I've also tried clearing all Google services' caches to no avail.

My phone is a Nokia XR20 with Android 13 and Quickstep as Launcher (Android One)

How can I activate my quick setting tile again?

Comment: I don't use wallet but this may be a worth a try-hide the wallet tile by editing quick setting tiles, reboot and unhide// for some reason this helped me way back and I didn't investigate further// Alternatively, clear the data of wallet app and re-enter the card details

Comment: Both did not work, but thanks for those suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the Payback App set itself as default payment provider despite not even being a payment method. After uninstalling the Payback app, the wallet was working again.